# MySql EF Code First migrations VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, entity-framework

I have been playing around with Entity Framework and MySql using the Code First approach,

When I run my code against a newly created MySql Server with no databases etc (apart from the defaults) It creates the database and tables according to the classes I have created.  My issue is and I don't know if I'm doing this right is, if I make a change to my model class for example add a new property I would expect a new column to be added to that particular table.  However this isn't the case instead I'm getting an error

```
Unknown column: 'Extent1.Email' in 'field list'
```

I know this is because I have made a change to the class, but I am under the impression that EF would be able to make that change automatically to the database.

I have Installed

EF 6.1.1

MySql.Data 6.9.3

MySql.Data.Entity 6.9.3

Answer (score 0):

All your db initialization takes place in

```
 Interface IDatabaseInitializer(Of In TContext As System.Data.Entity.DbContext)
```

You can set it in your `DbContext`s constructor using `Entity.Database.SetInitializer()` or configure it in your `Web.config` in `<entityFramework><contexts><context><databaseInititalizer>`.

To get your new columns in your existing database, you need to either do the necessary migrations (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/JJ591621.aspx) or you drop and recreate the database on every model change (which is what the `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` implementation of `IDatabaseInitializer` does, see http://www.adfa.se/Archive/2013/02/01/database-initializers-in-ef-code-first).

Without further information I recommend you to do the latter.